# Hide group if user is not logged in and all items in group require login

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of items, sorted into groups. When the user is not logged in, I print only the items that don't require login.

```
$previous_group = '';
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if($previous_group != $item['group']) {
        // Add dividers
        if($previous_group != '') echo '</ul>';
        echo '<h3>'.$item['group'].'</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    $previous_group = $item['group'];

    if($item['login_required'] !== 'true' || ($item['login_required'] == 'true' && $isLoggedIn != false)) {
        echo '<li>'.$item['title'].'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hpw-1nu)

How can I hide the header for a group that doesn't have any items because the user isn't logged in? For example, the "food" category in the PhpFiddle example.

I could just go through the array twice, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$previous_group = '';
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if($previous_group != $item['group'] && ($item['login_required'] == 'false' || $isLoggedIn == 'true')) {
        // Add dividers
        if($previous_group != ''){echo '</ul>';}
            echo '<h3>'.$item['group'].'</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';

    }
    $previous_group = $item['group'];

    if($item['login_required'] !== 'true' || ($item['login_required'] == 'true' && $isLoggedIn != false)) {
        echo '<li>'.$item['title'].'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one iteration:

```
$previous_group = '';
$group_content = '';
$last_key = end(array_keys($arr));
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    if (!$previous_group) $previous_group = $item['group'];
    if ($key === $last_key && $previous_group == $item['group'] && ($item['login_required'] !== 'true' || ($item['login_required'] == 'true' && $isLoggedIn != false))) $group_content .= '<li>'.$item['title'].'</li>';
        if ($group_content) {
            echo '<h3>'.$item['group'].'</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
            echo $group_content;
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        $previous_group = $item['group'];
        $group_content = '';
    }

    if($item['login_required'] !== 'true' || ($item['login_required'] == 'true' && $isLoggedIn != false)) {
        $group_content .= '<li>'.$item['title'].'</li>';
    }
}
```

However, doing more than one iteration will give you cleaner code.